# Connected Nodes List

Tags: blockchain.info

List of nodes `blockchain.info` is connected to...

Total Connected: 0

[Link on blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/connected-nodes)

This service is temporarily unavailable?

Comment: Yep, for a week.

Comment: is it somehow connected with the release of version 0.15?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know / I don't think so.